# Calculation step in deriving Hamiltonian from Lagrangian

Tags: summation, partial-derivative, matrix-equations

Suppose we have the following equation :

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}\dot{q_i}\space T_{ij}\space\dot{q_j}$$

Here $T_{ij}$ is a symmetric matrix, that depends on $q_i,t$. Suppose, I want to evaluate $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q_j}}$. So now we have,

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q_k}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial }{\partial\dot{q_k}}\sum_{ij}\dot{q_i}\space T_{ij}\space\dot{q_j}$$

In one of the lecture notes, my professor wrote that this is equivalent to,

$$\sum_i T_{ik}\space\dot{q_k}$$

However, this doesn't seem correct to me. According to me,

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q_k}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial }{\partial\dot{q_k}}\sum_{ij}\dot{q_i}\space T_{ij}\space\dot{q_j}=\sum_i T_{ik}\space\dot{q_i}$$

This should be the correct equation ( note that I've replaced $\dot{q_k}$ by $\dot{q_i}$, which is what we are summing over. )

Suppose both $i,j$ range from $1$ to $3$. Then according to my teacher,

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_3}}=T_{13}\dot{q_3}+T_{23}\dot{q_3}+T_{33}\dot{q_3}$$

According to me however,

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_3}}=T_{13}\dot{q_1}+T_{23}\dot{q_2}+T_{33}\dot{q_3}$$

Can someone tell me who is correct ? Was there a simple printing error in my teacher's notes, or am I making an obvious mistake in here ?

Comment: I am wondering who instant downvoted this question ...

Comment: Your indices are a bit messed up. If you want a contraction you need above and lower indice. In first equation, I would have written $\dot{q}^i T_{ij} \dot{q}^j$ but I suppose if you know what you are doing it is fine

Comment: Secondly, you're abusing notation a bit when you did the partial derivative, you should do the partial with a new index. Otherwise there is a conceptual difficulty of discerning between summation variables and the derivative variables

Comment: is T_{ij} independent of position?

Comment: @Aplateofmomos is the notation a little clear now ? And no, $T_{ij}$ depends on the position and time variables. This is actually from the derivation of the Hamiltonian from the Lagrangian. $L$ is just the part of the lagrangian with the quadratic velocity terms.

Comment: I am amazed that in the final summation no derivative of $T_{ij}$ came.. maybe there are some more property of it that you haven't told?

Comment: @Aplateofmomos the elements of $T_ij$ depend only on $q_i$ and $t$, and not on the $\dot{q_i}$ terms, and so, when we are doing partial derivative with respect to $\dot{q_k}$, it would act as a constant, I guess.

Comment: Ok, I'll show the correct working assuming that then

Comment: @Aplateofmomos thank you so much. I found this expression, by just expanding the summation and doing the partial derivative term by term, assuming I didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: You should really learn how to put the index correctly. I suggest you read Pavel Grinfeld's Introduction to Tensor Analysis. It really helps out to differentiate between what things are conceptually.

Comment: Do you get it a 100% ? If something is not clear I can edit the answer

Comment: @Aplateofmomos thank you so much, I understood this. Moreover, I think my mistake here was to not use the covariant and contravariant indices properly. I'll look up the reference on tensor notation surely.

Comment: Hi @Nakshatra could you please edit the question to add in the context were it came from? It'll make the question more easier to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have,

$$ L = \frac12 \sum \dot{q}_i T_{ij} \dot{q}_j$$

Taking the derivative of both side with $p$th coordinate and interchanging derivative with sum:

$$ \partial_{\dot{q}_p} L = \frac12 \sum \partial_{\dot{q}_p}  (\dot{q}_i T_{ij} \dot{q}_j)$$

Tricky term is $\partial_{\dot{q}_p}  (\dot{q}_i T_{ij} \dot{q}_j)$, we will work that out seperately:

$$ \partial_{\dot{q}_p}  (\dot{q}_i T_{ij} \dot{q}_j)= \delta_{ip} T_{ij} \dot{q}_j + \dot{q}_i T_{ij} \delta_{pj}  $$

Now, let's put this back in the summation:

$$ \partial_{\dot{q}_p} L = \frac12 \sum_{i,j} \delta_{ip} T_{ij} \dot{q}_j + \dot{q}_i T_{ij} \delta_{pj}  + \dot{q}_i \dot{q}_j\partial_{\dot{q}_p} T_{ij} = \frac12 \left[\sum_{i,j} \delta_{ip} T_{ij} \dot{q}_j  + \sum_{i,j} \dot{q}_i T_{ij} \delta_{pj} \right]$$

Now suppose we consider the second summation $ \sum_{i,j} \dot{q}_i T_{ij} \delta_{pj}$, since $i,j$ are dummy and further more the matrix is symmetric we can swap $i <--> j$, this gives the same thing as first term giving us:

$$ \partial_{\dot{q}_p} L=  \sum_{i,j} \dot{q}_i T_{ij} \delta_{pj}$$

At this point , we can use the property of the $\delta$ symbol. Since the it is only equal $1$ when $p=j$, we can replace all our $j$ with $p$:

$$ \partial_{\dot{q}_p} L=  \sum_{i,p} \dot{q}_i T_{ip} $$

But, $p$ is just one number (derivative index, so we have:

$$ \partial_{\dot{q}_p} L=  \sum_{i} \dot{q}_i T_{ip} = \dot{q}_1 T_{1p} + \dot{q}_2 T_{2p} + \dot{q}_3 T_{3p} $$

*:Note that I am abusing tensor notation a bit, but I am doing it so that it is smthn OP is familiar with. Many physics book don't get the right index placement so who cares anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Einstein summation to clear things up.
$$L=\frac{1}{2}T_{ij}\dot{q_i}\dot{q_j}$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_k}}=\frac{1}{2}T_{ij}\left[\dot{q_i}\frac{\partial \dot{q_j}}{\partial \dot{q_k}}+\dot{q_j}\frac{\partial \dot{q_i}}{\partial \dot{q_k}}\right]=\frac{1}{2}T_{ij}[\dot{q_i}\delta_{jk}+\dot{q_j}\delta_{ik}]=\frac{1}{2}T_{ij}\dot{q_i}\delta_{jk}+\frac{1}{2}T_{ij}\dot{q_j}\delta_{ik}=\frac{1}{2}\dot{q_i}T_{ij}\delta_{jk}+\frac{1}{2}\dot{q_j}T_{ij}\delta_{ik}=\frac{1}{2}\dot{q_i}T_{ik}+\frac{1}{2}\dot{q_j}T_{jk}$$ where we have used $T_{ij}=T_{ji}$ for evaluation of the second term in the sum. Since the summation is over $i,j$ these two are really the same quanity, hence we have $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_k}}=\dot{q_i}T_{ik}=\sum_i\dot{q_i}T_{ik}$$
So$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_3}}= \dot{q_1}T_{13}+\dot{q_2}T_{23}+\dot{q_3}T_{33}$$
It would seem that you are correct, not the professor.

Comment: Good answer. But.. how does this answer say something I haven't said o_o

Comment: @Aplateofmomos It doesn't say anything new, but I feel that it shows a bit more clearly how terms get condensed with the Kronecker delta and Einstein summation.

Comment: Don't take me in the wrong way, if your idea was to write it in Einstein notation your indices are all messed up. Here you are considering covariant and contra as total same. But disregarding that , reason I wrote way I did is because idts OP is well versed with einstein notation

Comment: @Aplateofmomos The concern with covariance/contravariance doesn't arise here because we are not treating the Kronecker delta as a $(1,1)$ tensor in this calculation.

Comment: I mean however you treat it, there is a conceptual depth to it rather than index bashing. The indical signature tells you how they transform. The way you wrote suggest it not even is a tensor. Well it is so with me as well but that was mostly intentional